# Different page layout on mobile devices

Tags: page-layout

Is it possible to show one page layout if the user logs on via the website, and another layout if the user logs on via Salesforce 1?
I only found instructions to assign a mobile layout to a user profile, but that's not what I was looking for, because I do want the user to have access to both layouts, depending on how they log on.
Tia.

Answer (score 1):

I smell some intense visualforce coding sessions in your near future!

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxyTAAQ

And as an idea suggested ONLY a  year ago - you have way more chances to master visualforce,apex,SQL, a bunch of other IT-related stuff, get an MBA, give birth to a baby, travel around the world and that thing is still going to be on the roadmap\under review by product team.
Good luck!